# Syllable structure rules

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-formation

Recently, I've started learning Korean, so please don't get mad if my question sounds stupid. My problem is that I don't know whether a consonant is a part of a three-letter syllable or a separate syllable.

For example, if we take this word

> 학교 - school

As I understand, the reason why ㅎ and ㅏ (as well as ㄱ and ㅛ) are put together is that the syllable with a vowel should always follow the rule 'consonant (on the left/top) + vowel (on the right/bottom)'. However, the syllable with a single consonant doesn't need anything added. Therefore, theoretically we can write the same word as

> 하ㄱ교

But this is considered to be wrong. Can you explain why?

Comment: Why do you think this is theoretically correct? Please link where you read this is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that `학` is not a *syllable with a single consonant*. It has two (written) consonants; one at the beginning (cho-seong) and another at the end (jong-seong). So for a syllable with two consonants (C-V-C syllables), the *rule* is 'cho-soeng (on the left/top) + vowel (on the right/middle) + jong-seong (on the bottom)'.

(Note that when the word `학교` is read, the first syllable usually sounds like just `/하/`, so there's the discrepancy between how you read and how you write).

Answer (score 0):

The rule of the Korean alphabet-*한글* is that the syllable cannot be written only with consonants. So, `하ㄱ교` is wrong since `ㄱ` has no vowel.

(Edit: In Korean writing system, each letter refers to each syllable. And the 'letter' does not mean single characters like `ㄱ` or `ㅏ`. To form a letter, at least one consonant and one vowel must be combined together. If you want to make sounds with no consonants, there is a placeholder `ㅇ` to be used like `아` for `ㅏ` sound and `오` for `ㅗ` sound, etc.)

This is also why you can often observe words like `버스` for `bus`. The original word `bus` ends with the `s` sound, so the Korean word should be `버ㅅ` for the correct sound representation. But since Korean alphabet does not allow `ㅅ` to be used alone, `ㅡ` was added to form `스`, which is a syllable with most similar sound to `s` in `bus`.

Comment: "하ㄱ교 is wrong since ㄱ has no vowel." is not true. The first `ㄱ` has a preceding vowel `ㅏ`.

Comment: @krim You're right, maybe I used the missleading expression. In Korean writing system, each 'combined' character refere to each syllable, and no consonant or vowel can be written alone. (There is a placeholder `ㅇ`  to represent the vowel sound.) What I wanted to point out was that `ㄱ` alone cannot be written to make a word.